# In WinDBG/SOS.DLL: How can I save all modules/assemblies listed by !DumpDomain to disk at once?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, disassembly, sos

I have an app that loads a bunch of `dlls` dynamically through a `memorystream` at runtime. Using WinDBG I can see the loaded modules when using the command !DumpDomain. Using other commands `(like ! lm)` does not show/list these hidden `dlls`.

Now I want to save these `dlls` to disk by using the `!SaveModule` [ModuleNumber from !DumpDomain list] command. It works perfectly but the thing is I have to do it manually for each module. I want to *automate* this process and found the following code:

```
!for_each_module .if ($spat ("${@#ImageName}","*.exe")) { !SaveModule ${@#Base} c:\temp\${@#ModuleName}.exe } .else { !SaveModule ${@#Base} c:\temp\${@#ModuleName}.dll }
```

The problem with this code is that the code actually does not export the desired hidden `dlls`. I think it has something to do that "for_each_module" does not include modules from the !DumpDomain command.

---

- Does anybody have a solution for that? Or
- Is there a better way to save the `dlls` to disk?

---

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET modules are not listed with lm so it is not in .for_each_module

In order to save managed modules, do this:

1. Get NetExt extension: https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext/releases
2. Use !wmodule command: https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext#wmodule

```
!wmodule -managed -saveto c:\temp\
```

To avoid saving Microsoft modules (like System.Web.dll), use this command instead:

```
!wmodule -managed -noms -saveto c:\temp\
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Unfortunately I get an exception when using the !wmodule command (e0434352 Exception in netext.wmodule debugger extension. PC: 00007ffe`30e9a839  VA: 00000000`00000000  R/W: 80004003  Parameter: 00000000`00000000). The extension seem to work in general because other commands such as !windex -tree are working. I only receive the exception when using the !wmodule command. Any ideas why that may happen?

Comment: I made some changes that were added to new versions. Please verify whether you have the latest. I tested on 32-bit dump as your dump and it worked:

0:010> .load c:\x86\netext
netext version 2.1.53.5000 Dec  4 2019
(...)

0:010> !wmodule -managed -noms -saveto c:\temp\deleteme
Saved 'c:\temp\deleteme\TestArray.exe' successfully

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem by doing this all in a 32Bit VM. The only issue I have now is, that the desired modules all have the exact same (file)name. And when using !wmodule only one module (I guess the first one in the list) is actually saved while the others are skipped because the extension thinks that the file is already available on disk. Any tip on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to run the command to save all files? !wmodule -saveto c:\temp

Comment: Having the same name is a problem indeed. I will fix it and let you know when the new version is up and running.

Comment: That's awesome. I guess the extension would need to add some random chars to the filenames or add a number at the end in order to save them. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: NetExt now saves modules with same name as long as the content is different. The new name is created based on checksum, size and code size. The syntax is the same. Version 2.1.54.5000 and beyond. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I cannot confirm a positive result, unfortunately. When taking a look at the modules which share the same name, !DumpDomain lists over 50 focal modules. !wmodule lists only 1 of the 50. Now one could assume the other 49 have the same checksum and thus the modules are not shown/exported but in fact I dumped them all manually in meantime and although many focal modules have the same checksum indeed, many are different but still are neither shown (!wmodule -noms) nor exported (!wmodule -noms -saveto).

Comment: If they are dynamic modules they are not full PE files and thus there may be a way of making a PE out of it, it would be very complicated to do so and will require a lot of extra code.

Comment: They are dynamic, indeed. Now I understand. Thank you for your help nonetheless.